# Why is docker-compose failing with ERROR internal load metadata?

Tags: docker

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

ltsc2022: Pulling from windows/servercore
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Or when trying to build the following docker image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
RUN PowerShell -Command New-Item -Path "C:\\" -ItemType "directory" -Name "UiPath"; \
    Invoke-WebRequest "https://download.uipath.com/UiPathStudio.msi" -OutFile "C:\\UiPathStudio.msi"; \
    Start-Process C:\\UiPathStudio.msi -ArgumentList 'ADDLOCAL=DesktopFeature,Robot,Studio APPLICATIONFOLDER=C:\\UiPath /quiet' -Wait; \
    Remove-Item "C:\\UiPathStudio.msi" -Force; \
    Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force; \
    Register-PSRepository -Name UiPath -SourceLocation https://www.myget.org/F/uipath-dev/api/v2; \
    Install-Module -Repository UiPath -Name UiPath.Powershell -Force
CMD ["cmd"]
```

### => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019                                                                                                                          0.9s

> [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019:

---

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:2b33eda096538c803fbf0c03dc7ea42c3c1b713e30aae03116d989867eda2bf8: not found

What am I doing wrong?